# Refresh token expire in 2 days in quickbook

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, refresh-token

Refresh Token for Quickbooks expiring after 2 day

Refresh Token for Quickbooks expiring after 1 day

Answer (score 2):

Yes, every 24 hours the refresh token gets changed.

Reference - https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/oauth-2.0#step-5-exchange-authorization-code-for-refresh-and-access-tokens#understand-token-expiration

As per the doc -

> Even though the refresh token is valid for 100 days, the value of
>   refresh token can change every 24-26 hour period. Hence, you might
>   encounter a situation where the request token that you received first
>   is different than the latest one. As a best practice, always store the
>   latest refresh token received from the API response and use that to
>   make subsequent calls to obtain a new pair of tokens.

Comment: How does a refresh token have a 100 day validity but can change after a day??

Comment: I think of it as a chain of refresh tokens that is valid for 100 days. No single refresh token is guaranteed to last more than the 24h period.  However, every time you use the refresh token, you can check for a new (latest in the chain) refresh token from the API response and store that for the next refresh.